# Find the validity of the following statement: There exists a monomorphism from a group of order $30$ into a group of order $100.$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-homomorphism

Find the validity of the following statement: There exists a monomorphism from a group of order $30$ into a group of order $100.$

I don't know how to solve these type of problems. Of course, this statement might be true but how to demonstrate a monomorphism between two *arbitary* groups, I have no idea about it. There should not exist any isomorphism between such groups but is a homomorphism at all possible? This seems absurd to me.

*I found this problem in a handout which contained a number of problems,so, I have no idea about the source of this problem. There was no further details in it, so I myself cant provide further clarity to it. But still, this seemed interesting so I thought about posting it.*

Comment: I'm not sure whether this has been said to you before but: don't use `$text$` for italic text, use `*text*` instead; compare $text$ to *text* respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that a group $G$ of $30$ elements will have an subgroup $H$ of order $3$,say, $\lbrace 1,a,a^2 \rbrace$ (By Cauchy's theorem).

If there was a monomorphism into a group $G'$ of order $100$, what would be the order of the element $f(a)$ in $G'$? What about the order of the element $f(a^2)$ in $G'$?

---

$\textbf{Edit:}$ What elements of a group are of order $1$?

Comment: Nice one! Ok, so if $G$ has an element of of $3$ i.e $a$ , then $o(f(a))|3$ and $o(f(a))|100$ , so $o(f(a))=1$  also, $o(f(a^2))=1$ but then ?

Comment: The identity element

Comment: So, $f(1)=f(a)=f(a^2)=1?$ Can this function be injective?

Comment: Are you implying both $f(a)=f(a^2)=e$ but $a\neq a^2$ thus, $f$ is not a monomorphism,  right?

Comment: You posted your comment before my comment, but so much thanks for your clarifications! I remain highly grateful to you.

Comment: This is common trick in group theory questions. So, it would be worth your while to remember.

Answer (score 1):

If $f\colon G\to H$ is an homomorphism, then $f(G)\le H$ and hence (Lagrange) $|f(G)|$ divides $|H|$. If $f$ is also injective, then $|f(G)|=|G|$. But in your case $|G|=30$ does not divide $|H|=100$. So no, such a monomorphism doesn't exist.